# Wget connection interrupt

Tags: linux, wget

I'm downloading a large website using linux Wget command

```
wget --mirror -c -e robots=off http://www.largewebsite.com
```

Is there a way I can resume downloading after switching off the computer?

Comment: I think the `-c` flags is for this. Just restart the same command after poweron. See [Wget documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/index.html)

Comment: Shall I terminate downloading with Ctrl+c or just switch off computer without terminating?

Answer (score 1):

If the server you were downloading from supports resuming connections,you can kill the wget process and restart it with the `-c` command.